# PHP mail() sending to gmail. yahoo, aol but not to my domain email

Tags: php

I had a mail function on a certain server. it works fine including attachments when sending to gmail, yahoo, aol and other email providers. but the to email value is an email from another domain (test@mysampledomain.com). the email is not received.

I also tested sending to the email using aol, gmail and yahoo, the email was received. Is there anything I'm missing that's why it is not sending?

Comment: Have you checked your receiving server's logs to see if your PHP box is actually connecting and trying to send an email?

Comment: did you add your domain in your dns  (even manually) ?

Comment: also enable php mail() debug mode and see if there are any errors received when e-mail is sent(caused by that particular domain)

Comment: I've ran into problems with mails coming from `mail` being silently killed by a certain overzealous anti-spam solution. If everything else checks out, you might want to ensure that is not the case.

Comment: @RudiVisser i'll be checking the logs.

Comment: @binogure not sure if the admins added the domain. In any case, can you give me a link where i could learn to add the dns?
thanks for the response...